# Session Persistance Issues Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant

I keep having the problem on setting up my environment. Here is the spec:

System: Windows 8.1 x64

PHP: 5.6.10

Vagrant: 1.7.0

Laravel Homestead: https://github.com/laravel/homestead

As I am new to the framework I get that it has the problem with Session Persistance Issues. Here is the log of the error i get when I open up the page in the browser.

https://gist.github.com/brainiac080195/e21db5d122c367b48fa4

Comment: This is nothing to do with sessions, the error is about writing the compiled view file. What is the value of `compiled` in `config/view.php`?

Comment: what are the permissions on those folder ?

Comment: @FredericHenri 'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')) drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Sep 21 11:00 config

Comment: weird, for some reason it is trying to write it to root (/) you must have a setting somewhere that is causing this

Comment: @fire any idea where this setting could be?

Comment: Not without seeing your entire codebase ;)

Comment: Can you do a gist of the whole `config/view.php` file?

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/brainiac080195/f9d870cdc89b29cf38d2)
`config/view.php` @fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was trivial. Bad setup documentation. /storage folder was added to exclude folder from local synchronization. The folder wasn't even pushed to the vagrant. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about session, this is about permission denied. Give permissions to your Storage, Bootstrap and to Vendor directory. Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: `chmod -R 777` storage and `chmod -R 777` bootsrap didn't help

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 3 vagrant vagrant 4096 Sep 21 11:04 storage`
`drwxrwxrwx 3 vagrant vagrant 4096 Sep 21 11:00 bootstrap`

Comment: give permission like chmod -R 775 /storage to both

Comment: in window 8 follow this.... http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/take-ownership-of-files-folder-and-change-permissions-in-windows-8/

Comment: no effect current permission `drwxrwxr-x 3` on both

Comment: Permission denied to this file: '/home/vagrant/www/api.mergus.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php' give permission to vendor folder 775 also...

Comment: `chmod -R 775 vendor` nothing changed

Comment: have you checked permission in UI (window) ?

Comment: One does not simply set 777 to the whole directory. Use only user/group permissions you really need. Mostly like 750, 620, 660,...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `php.ini` file, look for `session.save_path` and set it to a direcotry which is actually writable for the user running the webserver / php-worker.

I see you are using vagrant with linux and not windows.

```
/home/vagrant/www/api.example.dev/resources/views/welcome.blade.php
```

So setting `/tmp/` is a good value for the session save path.

Comment: ok I found the php.ini file with FileZila in /etc/php5/cli. But i am not able to edit the file or replace it. I wanted to change the the line `session.save_path = "N;/path"` to `session.save_path = "/tmp"`

Comment: its not the `cli` one. it's `/etc/php5/fpm` or `/etc/php5/apache` or something like that. you need to be root to edit the file `sudo su -` or `su -`